# How to convert a T-SQL column type and data in-place?

Tags: database, t-sql

I have a SQL Server 2005 database for a web site that stores user passwords in plaintext, and I would like to hash and salt them. I know how to use the `HashBytes` function to get and compare hashes, but I don't know the best way to go about converting the existing password column data. It's currently stored as a `varchar(50)` column and I would like to use `binary(20)` since I'm planning on using SHA-1.

I was thinking about `SELECT INTO` a temporary table, `ALTER` the existing column type, then `INSERT` the hashed and salted passwords back where the user ID's match. Is this a valid approach? Is there a way to do it in-place without a temp table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just [store the binary info as a hex string](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx). This has some benefits:

- Allows easy in-place UPDATE query
- No need for temp tables
- No need to change the structure of the table (your end result is a string)

I suggest writing functions to help you with the salting/hashing/hex-conversion (and vice versa.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Bear in mind adding a column will very likely cause page splits, so consider running maintenance soon to rebuild/defrag indexes and data pages.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD 'BinaryPW' binary(20)

UPDATE MyTable
SET BinaryPW = MyHashFunction(VarCharPW)

UPDATE MyTable
SET VarCharPW = ''
```